# POST array of objects using req.body parser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to post a simple request which includes array of objects. I have created a model and passing the data as per the model.
I am having trouble accessing body parameters as it contains array of data.
I am able to store line item data by **req.body.tasks[0]**
which is not a standrad way of storing details in mongodb.
I am looking for a standrad way of storing array of data in mongodb

Controller:

```
let createBug = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.tasks[0].subtask[0].description)
  for (var key in req.body) {
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      item = req.body[key];
      console.log(item);
    }
  }
  const createBug = new listModel({
    title: req.body.title,
    tasks: [{
      title: req.body.tasks[0].title,
      description: req.body.tasks[0].description,
      subtask: [{
        description: req.body.tasks[0].subtask[0].description
      }]
    }]
  }).save((error, data) => {
    if (data) {
      let apiResponse = response.generate(false, null, 201, data);
      res.status(201).send(apiResponse);
    } else {
      let apiResponse = response.generate(true, error, 404, null);
      res.status(404).send(apiResponse);
    }
  });
};
```

body:

```
{
"title":"sample title",
"tasks":[{
    "title": "task 1",
    "description":"task1 description",
    "subtask":[{
         "description":"task3 description"
    }]
    }]   
}
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mySchema = mongoose.Schema;
let subtask = new mySchema({
  description: String
})

let taskdata = new mySchema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  subtask: [subtask]
});

let listSchema = new mySchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },

  tasks: [taskdata],

  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

    ref: "users",
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("list", listSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things here a little bit. The request body exactly matches the model definitions, so you can simply pass the `req.body` object to your mongoose model:

```
const createBug = new listModel(req.body).save((error, data) => { ... }
```